# Read Mifare Classic tag with iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, nfc, mifare

According to Apple [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corenfc/nfcmifaretag) Mifare Classic tags are not supported explicitly. Apps like NFC Tools do not react on iPhone. Is it hardware restriction or this tag type can be read by some special low-level commands?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Mifare Classic is not supported by the NFC standard. They work on Android phones, which use the NFC protocol stack from NXP, because NXP added the support for Myfare Classic.

The structure of that chip is different from other RFID chips, which requires a different protocol in the software.